# F# Scala apply method

Tags: f#

I've seen there is a method one could use in a Scala type called apply. This would enable to call on a instance of the type as if it were a function or alike. Like for example the Scala list, one could write myList(0) for the first element in the list.

Is there anything like this in F#?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. You can write `myList.[0]` in F# to get the same effect - do you want the syntax to look exactly like function application?

Comment: Also do you want this for built-in types or just ones where you control the definition?

Comment: I would like to look exactly like the Scala definition. And its just for the types that I control. I presented the list example as is the one that I've used, but I intent to use it for other types that may not involve index in a list, for example.

Comment: There seems to be some magic in F# to recognise its own functions. They all inherit from `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`, and you can define your own types that do the same by overriding the abstract `Invoke` method, but the proper functions can be applied and the user-defined ones can't.

Comment: I think this might be because Scala is tending to highlight the OOP part a bit more - for F# I really don't like this - why lift a heavy Object into function status if you just could return a (closure) function in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

F# function application is based around the [`FSharpFunc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340302.aspx) type internally. For example, `(int -> int)` is represented as `FSharpFunc<int, int>`.

However the F# compiler seems to somehow know the difference between a real F# function and a manual attempt to implement one, at least when the implementation language is F#.

However, I was able to fake an F# function by defining it in C#:

```
public class Foo : FSharpFunc<int, int>
{
    public override int Invoke(int n)
    {
        return n + 1;
    }

}
```

and then from F#:

```
> let x = Foo() :> int -> int
val x : (int -> int)

> x 3;;
val it : int = 4
```

I couldn't work the same trick when defining `Foo` in F#, even when I define it in a separate compilation unit.

The F# compiler seems to insert an attribute `CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)` onto its own objects and I can't find a way to turn it off, but my C# works even if I put that attribute on manually.

Comment: Nice. I guess I should check the MSIL to see what it's the output to compare for differences.

Comment: I did that and couldn't spot anything, but I might be missing something. It's quite possible that the F# compiler looks for properties of the assembly as a whole to decide whether to treat it as F# or "other".